# Php Include properties within class

Tags: php, class, methods, properties

I'm having an issue calling a variable thats included in a class. What am I missing here? Thank you in advance for the support. Very much appreciated.

```
//index2.php
$var2 = 'var2';



//index.php
class something {
  __construct() {
    include('index2.php');    
  }
}


$run_it = new something();

echo $run_it->var2; //how do I call var2?
```

Comment: Haven't done PHP in a long time, but wouldn't `$var2` would simply just exist within the scope of `__construct()` and then be inaccessible thereafter?

Comment: Were no answers useful to you at all? If not, at least have the curtsy to upvote and if it did resolve the issue, mark it. If neither, at least comment on it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend property's of a class with including files. The class is defined as it is written. You have the following ways to add code to a class dynamically.

1. Extend a class.
2. Use traits (copy pasting functions into a class)
3. Use [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) (__call, __get, __set)

This example will print variables defined in the global scope (like your example) as you wanted it to do.
However, this is not the way it should be used and I suggest finding a different method of writing your class.

```
include 'somefile.php'; // <?php $var3 = 'testing' ?>

class foo{
  public $var2 = 'var2'; # should be declared within the class.

  public function __get($name){
    // property 'var3' is not defined in the class so this method is magically called instead.
    if(isset($GLOBALS[$name])){
      return $GLOBALS[$name]; // Here we return the value $var3 defined in the global scope.
    } else {
      trigger_error("Call to undefined variable '$name'");
    }
  }

  public function __construct(){ # Missed function statement.
    echo 'hello';
  }
}

$c = new foo();
echo $c->var3; // testing
```

Comment: How to remove your property to another file, and include it within the construct method?

Comment: You cannot, classes are defined as they are coded. Content cannot be added using include or require. You might want to take a look into traits that allows for reusable code or perhaps extending a class might do the job.

Comment: You could do `$this->var2 = include('index2.php');` in the constructor, assuming `index2.php` returns a value; Odd, but certainly one way to set a class property from an include file.

Comment: Extending it would do the job. But I wanted to explore my options... Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @jszobody very interesting... Thank you for your answer. It might just do the trick, but then I'd have to pass an array to get all the values... I might need to think about another way to approach this

Comment: @Andrew I strongly agree with "another approach." This just smells bad.

Comment: @Andrew I've added a workaround for this, but still this is not the way it should be coded.

Answer (score 0):

If your `index2.php` contains this:

```
$var2 = 'var2';
```

Then you can include that file to get access to `$var2`. You can then pass that variable to your `something` constructor as an argument:

```
//index.php

class something {

    public $var2;

    public function __construct($arg) {
        $this->var2 = $arg;
    }
}

include 'index2.php';

$run_it = new something($var2);

echo $run_it->var2;  // echos 'var2'
```

It's obvious there are other ways to do something like what you're attempting to do (there is usually more than one way to do most things), but really the most sensible way to get external data into your object is to pass it via constructor arguments.

If you don't do this, the class will forever depend on some other file existing in the correct location relative to the class or calling file, with all of the correct variables set in it. If that file is altered or moved, objects of that class may not function properly if they can even be instantiated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this. Kind of a strange way to do things but here goes:

index.php

```
<?php
class something{
  function __construct() {
    include('index2.php');    
  }
}

//s1
$s1 = new something();
$s1->var2 = 'var2 changed';

//s2
$s2 = new something();

//print em out
print_r($s1);
print_r($s2);
```

index2.php

```
<?php
    $this->var2 = 'var2'; //$this pseudo-variable works because we're including index2.php within the scope of our class instance
?>
```

Output
$ php a.php

```
something Object
(
    [var2] => var2 changed
)
something Object
(
    [var2] => var2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Xorifelse, you can do it with traits. example.

fields.php

```
trait Aa {

public $fields = [
  "name"=>"string->5",
  "number"=>"integer->3",
  ];
}
```

traits.php

```
include('fields.php');

class ABC {

use Aa;

public function __set($field,$value)
{
  if(array_key_exists($field,$this->fields))
  {
    $this->fields[$field] = $value;
   }
   else
   {
   $this->fields[$field] = null;
   }
}

public function __get($field)
{
  if(array_key_exists($field,$this->fields))
  {
   return $this->fields[$field];
  }
  else
  {
  return null;
  }
}
}
```

$a = new ABC();

$a->number = 111;

var_dump($a->fields);

```
array(2) {
["name"]=>
string(9) "string->5"
["number"]=>
int(111)
}
```

var_dump($a->number);

```
int(111)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php). Assuming your variables are in a file (e.g. filevars.php):

**filevars.php**

```
<?php
$name = 'myName';
$address = 'myAddress';
$country = 'myCountry';
$phones = array('123456789','987654321');
?>
```

You can add a method to your class (`getVars`) and define a property (`vars`) that wraps all variables existing in `filevars.php`:

**class-test.php**

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $vars;

    function getVars()
    {
        include ('filevars.php');
        $this->vars = get_defined_vars();
    }
}
?>
```

**Usage**

```
<?php
include ('class-test.php');
$myClass = new Test();
$myClass->getVars();
print_r($myClass->vars);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
{
    [name] => myName
    [address] => myAddress
    [country] => myCountry
    [phones] => Array
    {
        [0] => 123456789
        [1] => 987654321
    }
}
```

You can also refer any individual included variable, e.g.:
`echo $myClass->vars['country']; // myCountry`